# IIS URL redirection - igonre match all for some URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, redirect

I had to change previous URL pattern to something else. Earlier URL pattern was

www.testdomain.com/hotels/"city" and it changed to www.testdomain.com/hotel-"city"

Below is the redirection I have used that for.

```
<rule name="cityChange" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^hotels/(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.testdomain.com" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="www.testdomain.com/hotel-{R:1}"appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

Now I have another issue which is another URL I have used for the site is also redirecting to different one. That URL is,

> www.testdomain.com/hotels/'city'/'name'-'street'-'postalcode'

Since I have used a wildcard for /hotels/'city' to /hotel-'city' it changes above URL as

> www.testdomain.com/hotel-'city'/'name'-'street'-'postalcode'

as well. But that URL is not valid in the site and I do not want to replace "/" from "-" there.

How can I exclude this URL pattern from that wild card which I have mentioned above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have added ^ mark at the end. It will allow my second URL but not perform the redirection :(

Answer (score 1):

Can't be sure about that but did you try to add parentheses, like that ?

`<match url="^(hotels)/(.*)" />`

We did that for ou specific wildcard redirect :

```
<rule name="modeles-en" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(modeles-en)/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/models/{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Yes I added parentheses to match URL like this <match url="^(hotels)/(.*)" />